# Не добавляется товар в корзину Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Использую функцию

```
CModule::IncludeModule("sale");
$result = Add2BasketByProductID(44);
```

но товар не добавляется. как можно еще добавить товар в корзину?

Answer (score 1):

Документация битрикса достаточно исчерпывающе отвечает на ваш вопрос: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/basket.php#add2basketbybroductid

От себя добавлю, что при использовании функций модуля лучше делать это так:

```
if (CModule::IncludeModule("sale")) {
    $result = Add2BasketByProductID(44);
} else {
    echo('Нет модуля магазина');
}
```

Тогда вы сможете понять, на каком этапе не срабатывает функция.

Также хотелось бы узнать, что у вас находится в переменной `$result`. Цитата из документации:

> Код вставленной в корзину записи или False в случае ошибки.
>   Возможные ошибки:
>
> ```
> не установлен модуль Интернет-магазин;
> попытка поискового бота добавить товар в корзину (только при наличии модуля Веб-аналитика и вычисления бота на основе UserAgent);
> для указанного количества отсутствует цена либо нет типов цен, по которым пользователь может покупать;
> нет прав на чтение элемента инфоблока, цена которого добавляется в корзину.
> ```